# Conditional component styling fails with error

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

this is a simple styles depends from clicked.

```
const styles = {
  marginLeft: count * (-20) + 40 +'%'
}
```

And everything working if i will do it like that

```
return <div key={index} className={classnames({ 'food-photo': content })} style={styles}>
```

but i need to set those to 1st element  so inside map i got index and if i will do like that:

```
return <div key={index} className={classnames({ 'food-photo': content })} style={(index===0)?{styles}:''}>
```

error i got :

> _app.js:69 Uncaught Invariant Violation: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example,
>   style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass empty object if `index` is not equal to 0 and `styles` (without encompassing into curly braces) otherwise:

```
return <div key={index} className={classnames({ 'food-photo': content })} style={index===0?styles:{}}>
```

Following snippet is a quick and dirty proof of a concept:

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM

const styles = {
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        color: 'white',
        width: 50
      }

const Test = ({index}) => <div style={index===0?styles:{}}>Test</div>

render (
  (<div>
    <Test index={0}/>
    <Test index={1}/>
  </div>),
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: no, error: _app.js:69 Uncaught Invariant Violation: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX

Comment: finally xD also I find a solution to with passing 'margin-left' instead of marginLeft xD but keeping syntax at it should is better practice

Answer (score 0):

Just change the else case to pass an empty object. The below code will work fine.

```
return <div key={index} className={classnames({ 'food-photo': content })} style={(index===0) ? { ...styles } : {}}>
```

Comment: code doesn't work, also I can't find an error in console.
inside IDE:type '{ styles....}' is not assignable to type 'cssproperties'

Comment: Probably, the issue is the '%' in the styles. You might need to pass a numeric value

Comment: You may safely swap `{...styles}` for `styles` (without curly braces), check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60056291/11299053) in that regard